# How do I measure or track the progress of a command on a GNU distro?

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, progress

If I run

```
cp file1 file2
```

I'd like to be able to track it's progress. Is there a command I can use for this?

```
rsync --progress
```

has this, but is there something generic, usable for "any" command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `pv` to see the progress of any command that can transfer data through pipes.

See e.g. http://www.catonmat.net/blog/unix-utilities-pipe-viewer/ for explanations. This will not work for cp however, as it does not operate via pipes.

Beyond that, there's no general mechanism I am aware of. It would be difficult, since "progress" can mean different things to different commands.

BTW, `cp` has an option `-v` which lists files as they are copied, that can give you a rough idea of its progress.

**Edit:**

Though it might not directly answer your question: You can also just use a graphical file manager. Most provide a nice progress bar when copying / moving files (e.g. KDE's konqueror does).

Answer (score 1):

try append `--verbose` to commmands you are interested in, this will generally produce more infomation on progress.

Answer (score 0):

(Perhaps not quite what you're asking since it won't work for *any* command, but) to get a progress meter for *cp*, I sometimes (ab)use *scp*:

```
scp localhost:/path/to/source_file /path/to/destination
```

You will need the "localhost:" prefix on either the source or destination so *scp* won't fall back to a standard *cp*.

Comment: While this will work, it might be less efficient because you incur additional overhead for the network-transfer (even though it only uses the `localhost` pseudo-network-interface). However, as long as the copy is IO-bound, this will probably not matter.

Comment: At any rate, OP already uses `rsync --progress` for seeing progress during a copy operation.